# Facing very low accuracy in Stock price prediction using Time series analysis in python

Tags: python, time-series

Am working on a project to predict the Stock Prices listed in NYSE using Time Series Analysis.

I used the following code and at the end, I am facing the problem of the Predicted Stock Price deviating from the Actual stock price. To validate the same problem, the values of Mean Absolute Error, Mean Squared Error, Root Mean Squared Error values are way higher and out of limits.

I used the AutoArima function to predict the p,q and d values.

Sharing the codes I used and results I got.

Solution to this problem will be very useful and will be very much appreciated.

```
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from pmdarima.arima import auto_arima
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error
import math

result = seasonal_decompose(amer_air, model='multiplicative', freq = 30)
#fig = plt.figure()  
#fig = result.plot()  
#fig.set_size_inches(16, 9)

amerair_log = np.log(amer_air)

train_data, test_data = amerair_log[3:int(len(amerair_log)*0.7)], amerair_log[int(len(amerair_log)*0.7):]
#plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
#plt.grid(True)
#plt.xlabel('Dates')
#plt.ylabel('Closing Prices')
#plt.plot(amerair_log, 'green', label='Train data')
#plt.plot(test_data, 'blue', label='Test data')
#plt.legend()

model_autoARIMA = auto_arima(train_data, start_p=0, start_q=0,
                      test='adf',       # use adftest to find               optimal 'd'
                      max_p=3, max_q=3, # maximum p and q
                      m=1,              # frequency of series
                      d=None,           # let model determine 'd'
                      seasonal=False,   # No Seasonality
                      start_P=0, 
                      D=0, 
                      trace=True,
                      error_action='ignore',  
                      suppress_warnings=True, 
                      stepwise=True)
print(model_autoARIMA.summary())

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

model = ARIMA(train_data, order=(2, 1, 2))  
fitted = model.fit(disp=-1)  
print(fitted.summary())

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

fc, se, conf = fitted.forecast(756, alpha=0.05)  # 95% confidence
fc_series = pd.Series(fc, index=test_data.index)
lower_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 0], index=test_data.index)
upper_series = pd.Series(conf[:, 1], index=test_data.index)
#plt.figure(figsize=(12,5), dpi=100)
#plt.plot(train_data, label='training')
#plt.plot(test_data, color = 'blue', label='Actual Stock Price')
#plt.plot(fc_series, color = 'orange',label='Predicted Stock Price')
#plt.fill_between(lower_series.index, lower_series, upper_series,color='k', alpha=.10)
#plt.title('American Airlines Group Stock Price Prediction')
#plt.xlabel('Time')
#plt.ylabel('Actual Stock Price')
#plt.legend(loc='upper left', fontsize=8)
#plt.show()


**MSE: 1.1206900207259296
MAE: 0.8320023299808208
RMSE: 1.0586264783793808**
```

Comment: "Solution to this problem will be very useful" I can imagine that, but don't expect high accuracy predicting stock market.

Comment: A decent prediction accuracy would do. This is for learning purpose, so there isn't any real money involved

Comment: I agree with @sriram-k 100%, I would also add that backtesting in such occasions in highly difficult not to say unreliable.

Comment: the code you posted is basically plotting stuff. could you create a minimal example where you feed some data, get some prediction results and compare them with some expected results? We don;t need to plotting code to solve a prediction model issue

Comment: Have flagged the plotting codes as comments. Hope that should be okay

Comment: Where does the `amer_air` variable come from? Can you add the code which loads the data to the question?

Comment: ```amer_air = pd.read_csv("AAL.csv",index_col='Date')```

Comment: This code loads the following dataset. 

``` Open High Low Close Adj Close Volume
Date      
01-10-2010 1143.489990 1150.300049 1139.420044 1146.239990 1146.239990 4298910000
04-10-2010 1144.959961 1148.160034 1131.869995 1137.030029 1137.030029 3604110000```

Then since the Column of closing values is sufficient for the analysis dropped the other columns